# What technologies should I use to build gmail extensions

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm looking for some advice on what I "should" research for a particular project I've been asked to keep in mind.  I've been doing so for roughly 3 days by exploring various Google technologies, but none of them seems quite right.

I need to put together something for gmail that's roughly equivalent to something I've put together for Windows Outlook.  I'll explain in brief therefor what I've done for Outlook users, to give you a feel for what I'm looking for.  I put together an Outlook C# AddIn that when loaded by Outlook on startup adds a number of clickable tabs, buttons, and other assorted interface elements to the Outlook interface.  When you click them the C# code in my Add-In is invoked in various ways to carry out various activities, like archiving the email message that's currently selected in a remote database managed by one of our web applications.  It does this by calling a variety of Outlook C# APIs that are available to any loaded AddIn, to extract or manipulate various Outlook "objects".  Another thing it does on a button click is bring up a web browser the AddIn creates from a .Net class "webbrowser control" instance, essentially adding chrome to the IE "engine".  It also adds what it needs to to the DOM of that web browser to make a large number of Add-In C# functions callable by javascript code that might be running in pages of that browser, essentially giving our web applications a way to "ask" my AddIn to create Outlook contacts, tasks, messages etc on behalf of that application.  The gist of it is that the UI I add to the Outlook application can be used to make various web service calls to our applications (based on the state of various Outlook "objects" made visible/manageable by way of the Outlook C# API), and the state of the Outlook application can be manipulated by javascript code running in web application pages that happen to be loaded in the web browser it creates.

I need to support "similar" functionality with respect to the altogether different gmail beast (rather than a Windows application a browser based web app).  I feel a bit like I've been spinning in circles the last few days, while investigating.  I began by researching gmail Sidebar and Contextual gadgets, to add some roughly equivalent UI of my own to gmail, but found fairly quickly that I can't really get to any gmail APIs using them, only try to shoehorn what I've got into a set of triggered gmail "behaviors" supported by contextual gadgets, which I came to realize isn't really sufficient to support what I want.  Eventually I navigated my way to the set of developer pages describing Google Apps Script supported functionally, which seemed for a time like "the way to go" to provide me with hooks into gmail APIs.  I played a bit with them, making a web app script to collect the subject lines of all my gmail messages and dump them into a UI also built by the script, just to get an experimental quick feel for how things fit together.  The script works, but it seems pretty slow, taking roughly a minute to collect and display just 57 email subject lines.  And I can't really figure out how to get any script built UI into the gmail user interface.  I tried building a side bar gadget with the URL of my app script referenced (with no HTML or javascript in the content tag body at all).  An area is allocated to the gadget ok, but my script UI never appears in it.  After playing a bit unsuccessfully to get my script to run in an iframe in a completely different context, just experimenting again to see what I might be able to do, I'm beginning to get the impression that some security related caveat prevents it from building/displaying its interface in either an iframe or a gmail side bar gadget, though perhaps I'm just missing some essential piece of information.

My question is a bit big I know, but "should" I be looking to other Google technologies to build the sort of thing I have in mind, or am I "roughly" following a tenable track.  I'm looking for some rough architectural advice I guess, some hints about what maybe I should further explore.

Comment: I'm doing the same but other way around. Reusing the javascript from my chrome extension that integrates in Gmail into Outlook would be perfect. How did you do what you explained? I mean how do you use javascript inside a outlook addin?

Answer (score 2):

With Google Apps Script you cannot add anything to the Gmail interface. Putting it simply, it will not do what you want.

Now back to your problem, if sidebar and contextual gadgets are not enough for you. The only solution I see where you can really manipulate the page is via an add-on/extension/script installed on the users browser.

This approach is powerful, in the way that you can change the page as you like, but has its shortcomings as well. First, and more obvious, it's somewhat browser dependent and installed locally on a browser. Meaning that if the user switch computers or browsers, he'll need to re-install your add-on.

Also, you're somewhat dependent on gmail's "internal" structure. I say "somewhat" because that depends on how you coded your app. But they may make a change and break your app instantly, without any notice, since gmail's html-css structure is not a "published API".

Well, that's my 2 cents. I hope it helps.

Comment: It does.  And that path may be acceptable.  I'll start reading/playing with Chrome extension support, and bring up what it might mean for customers with my coworkers.  Thanks.

Comment: P.S. This Chrome extension/packaged app technology looks really very cool.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I helped. By the way, since you're new to stackoverflow, you should mark an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one (not saying that you should accept mine, it's just a tip). Another useful feature we have here is voting (up and down). You should use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use **JSF** and **rich faces**. this can give u a google gmail like looks and development with this is very easy and fast.

Happy Coding

Comment: Do you have a example for how these technologies can be used to solve the problem?